# Каким образом контролируется фокус слоёв?

Tags: android, шаблоны-проектирования, material-design

Предположим, есть некоторое окно, или диалог занимающий часть экрана при каком-либо действии.

И необходимо либо позволить пользователю указать этот диалог приоритетным, либо наоборот позволить пользоваться приложением во время его отображения.

Кто-то может сказать, что при появлении диалога задний слой автоматически дизейблится, на этот случай хочу напомнить про такой элемент, как Bottom Sheet.

Я не нашел в интернете статей или подробной информации работы над фокусом, то есть если скажем, пользователь должен работать конкретно с одной `view` в данный момент времени, каким образом это достигается?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если нужно позволить взаимодействие с другим контентом добавляем эту "панель" в разметку (в смысле в иерархию вьюх текущего окна, а не обязательно в xml). Если нужно запретить взаимодействие с другим контентом, то создаём диалог с этой панелью. Вот и всё собсно. Bottom Sheet так и реализован, есть контрол который добавляется в `CoordinatorLayout`, а есть диалог, который создаёт отдельное окно с отдельным `CoordinatorLayout` и добавляет туда контрол Bottom Sheet.

Comment: а что если нужно добавить контрол в `CoordinatorLayout` не как отдельное окно, но при этом с ограничениями отдельного `CoordinatorLayout` ?

Comment: а как вы при этом пользователю покажите без диалога что он может работать только с отдельной областью?

Comment: на самом деле я пытаюсь понять принцип действий.

Такие заморочки требует дизайн, не моя прихоть так сказать. Поэтому пытаюсь представить бест практис из ваших слов.